# Noise near 0 when plotting LerchPhi function

Tags: plotting, numerics, special-functions

What is happening near 0 when I plot the function `LerchPhi`?

```
Plot[LerchPhi[y^2, 1, 9/2], {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: bad plot]

Comment: Possible a numeric noise,try `Plot[{LerchPhi[y^2, 1, 9/2]}, {y, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}]`

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. See the tag description.

Comment: many thanks, but what if I needs its value for computing?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here, as already noted by Mariusz, is that severe cancellation is happening when evaluating near the origin.

A solution in this case is to use [a different representation of your function in terms of `Hypergeometric2F1[]`](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/26/01/02/01/), which performs better for tiny arguments:

```
Plot[2/9 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 9/2, 11/2, y^2], {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot of function]

Comment: May I ask why, under-the-hood, `LerchPhi` doesn't simply call `Hypergeometric2F1` for numerical evaluation?

Comment: I don't know either, honestly. (Probably a good suggestion to send to support.) Note that the same problem happens with `HurwitzLerchPhi[]`.

Answer (score 0):

"but what if I needs its value for computing?"

```
LerchPhi[y^2, 1, 9/2]

(* (-2 - (2*y^2)/3 - (2*y^4)/5 - 
      (2*y^6)/7 + (2*ArcTanh[y])/y)/y^8 *)

LerchPhi[0, 1, 9/2]

(* 2/9 *)
```

With machine precision near zero you get a bad result

```
LerchPhi[0.0001, 1., 4.5]

(* 0. *)
```

Using arbitrary precision

```
LerchPhi @@ SetPrecision[{0.0001, 1., 4.5}, 20]

(* 0.22 *)

Precision[%]

(* 1.60341 *)
```

Almost all precision is lost between input and output. It is much better to convert input to exact numbers and then convert exact output to numeric values

```
N[LerchPhi @@ ({0.0001, 1., 4.5} // Rationalize), 20]

(* 0.22224040557899892396 *)

Precision[%]

(* 20. *)
```